# There’s a Galton-Watson process in my random walk!

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

> Let $S_n$ be the simple nearest-neighbor random walk on the integers started at $S_0=1$. Define $T$ to be the time of the first visit to the origin, that is, the smallest $n\geqslant 1$ such that $S_n=0$. Define $Z_0=1$ and 
>   $$Z_k=\sum_{n=0}^{T-1}\mathsf 1_{\{X_n=k\text{ and } X_{n+1}=k+1}\}. $$ In words, $Z_k$ is the number of times that the random walk $X_n$ crosses from $k$ to $k+1$ before first visiting $0$.
>
> (A) Prove that the sequence $\{Z_k\}_{k\geqslant0}$ is a Galton-Watson process, and identify the offspring distribution as a geometric distribution.

I have no idea how to give a solution to this problem. Since the Galton-Watson process is about offspring and extinction. I don't know why it can be used to solve simple random walk problems.
And also I'm not sure why there is offspring distribution and why it is geometric? 
Thanks a lot! I'm totally torched by the stochastic process.

Comment: I edited the question into MathJax from the image; please check for errors. Also, $Z_k$ references $X_n$ but I believe it should be $S_n$? That may be a typo in the problem.

Comment: Also for reference and context, this question comes from these notes: http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/312/Branching.pdf

Comment: Hint: Note that $Z_k>0$ implies that $Z_{k-1}>0$, for $k\geqslant 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a random walk reflected at the x-axis or stopped when hitting $0$, or just about the first excursion of a random walk:

[image]

So, what you see (in red) is (a possible realization of) a binary Galton-Watson tree ($0$ or 2 children with probability $1/2$) with $exp(1)$-distributed lifetime. 
Given a tree like that, you can draw the random walk (which stops when hitting zero): A branching point is a local minimum, a leaf is a local maximum. 
With the right scaling you get a reflected brownian motion.

Of course, the construction is possible for all distributions and the random walk will just be something else!

The key message is, what Ted Harris said 1952: "Walks and trees are abstractly identical objects ... "

And regarding your exercise: You have fixed lifetimes of one period. So instead of $\exp(1)$ we look at $\delta_1$. The expected number of periods till the next downstep are two, so the offspring distribution should be $geo(1/2)$.

Comment: Just added something regarding your exercise!

Comment: Shouldn't your image have the random walk starting at $1$ instead of $0$?

Comment: That's just a matter of visualization, but yes! Regarding you question it is better to ignore the part of the path from $(0,0)$ to $(x,1)$!

Comment: Well, Thank you very much. The visualization is helpful for understanding. I believe I may still need some time to digest.